# Combining lines with similar angles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, merge, angles

I have a lines layer representing hedge lines. Each hedge is split at a 'junction'. I want to combine the hedgerow lines that are travelling in a similar direction to have only one hedge line. I can then put a point at each node.

The image shows 5 lines. The small red section in the middle is a 'hedge' in its own right. I want to combine it with two of the other lines to create only one line. I have a large dataset to do this on and so was wondering about calculating the angle of each line and merging similar lines.

[image: 5 lines of which 3 need to be merged]

Comment: Just to make sure I got this right, the small red line needs to stay there? This is correct geometry and topology?

Comment: Not sure if that achieves what you want, but try merging all lines, then convert from multipart to single parts

Comment: Which of the four skinnier lines do you want to move? Or do you want to move all four to the midpoint of the fat segment? Please [Edit] the Question (and maybe use Paint on the image)